# CentOS - Apache MaxRequestWorkers issue

Tags: centos, apache-2.4

I've had a problem with Apache since this morning, I can no longer access the websites.

I get the error: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting

I'm using the `mpm_event`.

Server memory: 15GB (16GB - 1 dedicated)

I tried increasing the parameters:

```
ServerLimit 750
ThreadsPerChild 25
MaxRequestWorkers 725
```

Another strange thing is linked to the fact that when I launch:
systemctl status httpd.service

In the processes I only see `/usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND` and therefore I can't even understand if there is some process/script that is blocking.

Thanks in advance,
Matteo

Comment: https://bobcares.com/blog/server-reached-maxrequestworkers-setting/. Also check `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf`

Comment: Also do a `grep -R "MaxRequestWorkers" /etc/apache2/` or `grep -R "MaxRequestWorkers"  /etc/httpd/`. And then restart apache `apachectl -k graceful`

Comment: Ok I checked the configuration but everything seems to be ok, could it be a DDoS attack?

Comment: You have to check the access logs for that, if you see at lot of requests coming in there. Or use this command `netstat -an | egrep ":80|:443" | egrep '^tcp' | grep -v LISTEN | awk '{print $5}' | egrep '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}' | sed 's/^\(.*:\)\?\(\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\{1,3\}\).*$/\2/' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | sed 's/::ffff`

Comment: The really strange thing is that until yesterday everything always went correctly using the prefork module. Yesterday morning it started to give problems so after some tests I switched to using the event module and changing the parameters. Even now it's very strange what happens, every now and then it crashes... I also checked the access logs and error logs but nothing strange.

Comment: Processes are heavier for CPU than threads. The advantage with mpm_event is that it has worker threads instead of processess, so instead of an obscene amount of processess (serverlimit), just have a few of them and many threads per process, example: serverlimit 5, threadsperchild 200, maxrequestworers 1000. Start like this and share the list of modules and your configs if it persists.